# How to prevent Image.file() in flutter from being laggy?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I am working on a flutter project and building a page where we have image folders as dropdown menu and as we select one, the page should display all the images present in that folder.
I have achieved this using platform channels, but the problem is, I am trying to load all those images in a `GridView` using `Image.file()`, and it loads all those images very very slow and the whole UI freezes.
How to fix it and make it smooth?

Comment: to show Images use  `FadeInImage` widget - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html

Comment: @anmol.majhail Image.file() can't be used inside FadeInImage() widget!

Comment: use - `FileImage()` in `FadeInImage`.  https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/FileImage-class.html

Answer (score -1):

It's likely that your app hits its allocated memory. Out of Memory error is thrown because the images being displayed and cached are full-sized images that are most likely resized (still takes a chunk of memory). I suggest generating thumbnails for the images that you'll display to save memory. There are a lot of helpful answers on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701654/how-can-i-read-from-disk-and-resize-an-image-in-flutter-dart) that you can choose from.

If you're just using the Image GridView as an image picker, you may want to consider using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin as an option.