# Flutter - save ImageProvider to file

Tags: image, flutter, dart, image-resizing

I need to resize image file and save it back to cache. To resize image:

```
ImageProvider img = ResizeImage.resizeIfNeeded(1024, null, FileImage(File(path)));
```

I guess `img` object contains resized image data. How to save it to file to access it when required?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is seeking an answer here, I'm happy to share my method for saving an ImageProvider to a file on the device. Please refer to the code below.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

final fileProvider = StateProvider<File?>((ref) => null);

class ImageProviderWidget extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final ImageProvider<Object> imageProvider;
  final Widget child;
  const ImageProviderWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.imageProvider,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _ImageProviderWidgetState();
}

class _ImageProviderWidgetState extends ConsumerState<ImageProviderWidget> {
  late final ImageStream _imageStream;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _imageStream = widget.imageProvider.resolve(ImageConfiguration.empty);
    _imageStream.addListener(_imageStreamListener());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageStream.removeListener(_imageStreamListener());
    super.dispose();
  }

  ImageStreamListener _imageStreamListener() {
    return ImageStreamListener(
      (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) async {
        ByteData? byteData =
            await image.image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
        if (byteData == null) return;
        final appStorage = await getDefaultDestinationDirectory();
        final fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        final file = File('${appStorage.path}/$fileName.png');
        await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
        ref.read(fileProvider.notifier).update((state) => file);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<Directory> getDefaultDestinationDirectory() async {
    final preferredDirectory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Pictures');

    return Platform.isAndroid
        ? preferredDirectory.existsSync()
            ? preferredDirectory
            : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()
        : await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final file = ref.watch(fileProvider);
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: file == null
            ? null
            : DecorationImage(
                image: FileImage(file),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
      ),
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are doing some very weird hack here, using loop and Future.delayed to wait for the image file to finish. Sure, most image would have been finished processed after 10 seconds, unless it's huge; but this feels so wrong and not elegant at all. You should probably perform setState or notify a provider instead.

Comment: @DanielWu Yes, you're right. I constrained myself to make this an external method, independent from the UI part. However, it seems impractical, especially when I have to set the timeout. Ideally, it would be better if I could run the listener elsewhere in the Flutter app UI. Therefore, I'll replace the old solution with a better one up there.

Answer (score -1):

As I see, you already resize your image. you can try this code to paste your new image. but be carefull for `img`, because it have to buffer like `5D FF A0`

```
ImageProvider img = ResizeImage.resizeIfNeeded(1024, null, FileImage(File(path)));

final File newImagePath = File("/example/path"); //pasting path

newImagePath.writeAsBytesSync(img);
```

Comment: `File.writeAsBytesSync` takes `List<int>` as a parameter, not `ImageProvider`

Comment: research how can you convert `ImageProvider` to `List<int>`

Comment: could you check this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701654/how-can-i-read-from-disk-and-resize-an-image-in-flutter-dart

Comment: I've seen that, but it does not meet my needs. I want to load reduced version, and avoid loading original image to save memory. If possible, without using any  platform specific code by myself