# What is the best way to resize images to fit a certain area?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am looking for a way to put random-sized network images into a fixed size area. The issue is the pictures can be random sizes. Is there a way to get images resized to fit a certain area? Any suggestions? I thought about expanded or aspect ratio but I don't really know how to take this approach.

This is my code so far:

```
child: Expanded(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0)),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read (from disk) and resize an image, in Flutter/Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701654/how-can-i-read-from-disk-and-resize-an-image-in-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 3):

```
Image(
 fit: BoxFit.cover, //or BoxFit.fill
 image: NetworkImage(
  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
  ),
),
```

With `BoxFit` you can fit your image to any size you want.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html

If you want to set the `borderRadius` of a photo, you can use `ClipRRect`.

Answer (score 0):

To make an Image fill its parent, simply wrap it into a FittedBox:

```
FittedBox(
  child: Image.asset('foo.png'),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
)
```

> FittedBox restricts its child widgets from growing its size beyond a
> certain limit. It re-scales them according to the size available. For
> instance, if the text is displayed inside a container, and the text is
> to be entered by the user. If the user enters a large string of text,
> then the container would grow beyond its allocated size. But, if we
> wrap it with FittedBox, then it would fit the text according to the
> size available. For large string, it would shrink its size, hence
> would fit in the container.

**Sytnax**

```
FittedBox({
   Key key,
   BoxFit fit: BoxFit.contain,
   AlignmentGeometry alignment: Alignment.center,
   Widget child
    }
)
```