# Resize Image Height and Width Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, file, size, pixel

How to resize image height and width from image picker and save it as a file.
I tried `decodeImage` and `copyResize` then `encodePng` but I have issue  it blocks ui thread, is there another way?

**[UPDATED]**

There are some solutions like:

- `ResizeImage`
- `instantiateImageCodec`

But how I use it and get the image as a file after resizing?

Comment: Does this answer's your question? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701654/how-can-i-read-from-disk-and-resize-an-image-in-flutter-dart

Comment: I did that like I said in the question, I had issue.  it blocks ui thread.

Comment: I found a solution in some answers like using ```ResizeImage``` but how I convert it then to a File?